# Как создать rtp сессию на xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sip, rtp

Используя этот код у меня получается дозваниваться, от абонента А до абонента В, но мне не удается передать голос. Если я правильно понял мне надо отправить `rtp session` в запросе при звонке другому абоненту. Но я не понимаю как это сделать на `Xamarin`. библиотека которой я пользуюсь  `sipsorcery`, это единственная библиотека которая подошла для `xamamrin` , ее поддерживают , и она бесплатная. Я около недели пробывал различные библиотеки и остановился на этой. Единственная ее проблема , в том что она ориентирована на Windows. Я читал ответ разработчиков на этот вопрос и на сколько я понял с xamamrin возможно передать голос и позвонить, вот их ответ на подобный вопрос  https://github.com/sipsorcery-org/sipsorcery/issues/220 .
В итоге я пришел к тому, что у меня не получается на xamarin сформировать `RTP Session` но удается позвонить.

Как показана в примере разработчиков:

```
IPTransport sipTransport = new SIPTransport();
SIPUDPChannel udpChannel = new SIPUDPChannel(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));
sipTransport.AddSIPChannel(udpChannel);
SIPUserAgent ua = new SIPUserAgent(sipTransport, null);

IMediaSession dummySession = new RtpAudioSession(new DummyAudioOptions { AudioSource = DummyAudioSourcesEnum.SineWave }, new List<SDPMediaFormatsEnum> { SDPMediaFormatsEnum.PCMU });
Task.Run(async () => await ua.Call("time@67.222.131.147", null, null, dummySession));
```

Вот мой код:

```
public class CallViewModel
    {
        string USERNAME = "1001";
        string PASSWORD = "1234";
        string DOMAIN = "192.168.0.105";
        int EXPIRY = 120;
        protected MediaRecorder recorder;

        SIPTransport sipTransport = new SIPTransport();
     
        public CallViewModel()
        {
            SIPRegistrationUserAgent regUserAgent = new SIPRegistrationUserAgent(sipTransport, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DOMAIN, EXPIRY);
            regUserAgent.RegistrationFailed += Failed;
            regUserAgent.RegistrationTemporaryFailure += Failure;
            regUserAgent.RegistrationRemoved += RegRemove;
            regUserAgent.RegistrationSuccessful += Success;
            regUserAgent.Start();
            myCall();
        }
        public  async Task myCall()
        {

          
             string DESTINATION = "192.168.0.105";
          string hostName = Dns.GetHostName(); // Retrive the Name of HOST  

          string myIP = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
          System.Net.IPAddress ipaddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(myIP);
         

          // Create a SIP user agent client that can be used to initiate calls to external SIP devices and place a call.

          SIPUDPChannel udpChannel = new SIPUDPChannel(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));
          sipTransport.AddSIPChannel(udpChannel);
          SIPClientUserAgent uac = new SIPClientUserAgent(sipTransport);

          SIPCallDescriptor callDescriptor = new SIPCallDescriptor("1001", "1234", "sip:1002@192.168.0.105", "<sip:1001@192.168.0.105>", null, null, null, null, SIPCallDirection.Out, "application/sdp", null, null);
          uac.Call(callDescriptor);
             
        }

        private void Success(SIPURI obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void RegRemove(SIPURI obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void Failure(SIPURI arg1, string arg2)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void Failed(SIPURI arg1, string arg2)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Comment: SIP создает RTP сессию, это часть логики протокола SIP. Он не может ее не создавать. Если это не работает, значит в принципе SIP не работает. RTP - это транспортный канал, по нему просто голос идет. Не думаю, что на уровне вашего кода это возможно решить. Скорее всего надо дорабатывать исходники используемой вами библиотеки. Кстати, как вы поняли, что оно не работает именно на уровне RTP?

Comment: @aepot Я всего лишь предполагаю, т.к в моем коде я ни где не создавал RtpSession, но звонок проходит(без голоса),